# How to hide the bottom edge on TextField?

Tags: flutter

How to hide the bottom edge on TextField?

```
 TextField(
     decoration: InputDecoration(
     hintText: '(201) 555-0123',
 ),
```

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

How are you?
You can set the border of InputDecoration to InputBorder.none.

```
child: TextField(
              decoration: InputDecoration(
                border: InputBorder.none,
                hintText: S.of(context).textHere,
                hintStyle: TextStyle(fontSize: 12),
              ),
              minLines: 5,
              maxLines: null,
              controller: _content,
              keyboardType: TextInputType.multiline,
              textCapitalization: TextCapitalization.sentences,
            ),
```

https://i.stack.imgur.com/trK69.png

Answer (score 1):

You can use the [`*border` parameters](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/material/TextField/TextField.html) of `TextField`:

```dart
TextField(
  decoration: InputDecoration(
    hintText: '(201) 555-0123',
    // Hides the border when the TextField is enabled
    enabledBorder: OutlineInputBorder(
      borderSide: const BorderSide(color: Colors.transparent),
    ),
    // Hides the border when you click the TextField
    focusedBorder: OutlineInputBorder(
      borderSide: const BorderSide(color: Colors.transparent),
    ),
    // Hides the border when the TextField is disabled
    disabledBorder: OutlineInputBorder(
      borderSide: const BorderSide(color: Colors.transparent),
    ),
  ),
)
```